# Alternative proof of the differential equation

Tags: calculus

Prove that:

If $y=(x^2-1)^n$, then

$y^{n+2}(1-x^2)-2xy^{n+1}+n(n+1)y^n=0$, where $y^n$ is nth derivative of $y$

My solution:
Taking log on both sides;

$\log y=n \log (x^2-1)$

$\implies y^{'}(x^2-1)=2nxy$

$\implies y^{'}2x+y^{''}(x^2-1)=2nxy^{'}+2ny$

Taking $n$ derivative throughout using leibnitz theorem gives;

$\implies 2ny^{n+1}+2ny^n+y^{n+2}(x^2-1)+2xny^{n+1}+ny^n(n-1)-2nxy^{n+1}-2n^2y^n-2ny^n=0 $(

Simplifying, the above equation leads to the answer.

Is my approach valid?

Is there any alternative solution possible, preferably using induction?